# замена function based views на class based views

Tags: python, django

В рамках обучения создал вьюху для вывода полной информации о Посте(сообщение)
на этой же странице выводятся комментарии к посту и форма для написания комментариев.
В ходе рефакторинга уже изменил несколько FBV на CBV, но тут уже почти сутки в ступоре.
подскажите какой generic class-based views здесь будет уместен?

```
def post_detail(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post.objects.select_related('author', 'group'),
                             id=post_id)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    comment_queryset = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)

    page_obj = paginator(comment_queryset, POST_PER_PAGE, request)

    context = {'post': post, 'form': form, 'page_obj': page_obj}
    return render(request, 'posts/post_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: [Вот этот подойдет](https://django.fun/ru/articles/tutorials/django-detailview-osnovy-ispolzovaniya/)

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать!

Comment: Если можно передать через model или queryset,  form в контекст через def get_context_data(self, **kwargs), то как comment_queryset с паджинатором  передать в контекст?

Comment: также, как и в функции `context['page_obj'] = paginator(comment_queryset, POST_PER_PAGE, request)`